# diffrence of two time in c++

Tags: c++, time

At first I get a time by

```
time_t t1 = time(0)
```

(is it right for getting current time?)
then

```
time_t t2 = time(0)
```

now I want the find the difference between t1 and t2 in milliseconds
I searched a lot but it didn't worked.
lots of casting problems and unable to change it to milliseconds
thanks for your help in advance

Comment: difftime: http://linux.die.net/man/3/difftime

Comment: You have C++11 features?

Comment: Thanks for all help. I searched in a wrong way. I tried to cast t1 - t2 in some strange way.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Use [`difftime`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/clibrary/ctime/difftime/):

```
double diff = difftime(t2, t1);
```

This gives you the difference in seconds. Multiply `diff` by `1000` to get milliseconds.

Comment: Thanks for all help. I searched in a wrong way. I tried to cast t1 - t2 in some strange way.

Comment: difftime will not have a fractional part because t1, t2 are integer types.

Comment: @MartinR , this happens in practice, but in theory `On POSIX systems, time_t is measured in seconds, and difftime is equivalent to arithmetic subtraction, but C and C++ allow fractional units for time_t. ` ( http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/chrono/difftime )

Answer (score 12):

`time()` returns an integer type giving the time since the epoch in seconds, therefore you will never get millisecond resolution. Use `gettimeofday()` instead, that gives a struct with seconds and microseconds:

```
struct timeval t1, t2;
gettimeofday(&t1, NULL);
/* ... */
gettimeofday(&t2, NULL);
int milliSeconds = (t2.tv_sec - t1.tv_sec) * 1000 + (t2.tv_usec - t1.tv_usec)/1000;
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is what you need: http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/clibrary/ctime/difftime/

Comment: Thanks for all help. I searched in a wrong way. I tried to cast t1 - t2 in some strange way.